# How do I move files based on a partial name in R

Tags: r

I have a folder with 2000+ .txt files in it and I want to copy some of these files into a new folder. The files are named "ABC1211_987XYZ.txt", "ABC1212_986XYZ.txt", "ABC1213_985XYZ.txt" etc...

In R, I have a vector containing a list of partial file names. The real vector has ~350 partial file names

```
group_1 <- c("ABC1211", "ABC1213", "ABC1220")
```

I want to use this vector to copy these files into a new folder using something like the following code, but I don't know how to work with only having part of the file names.

```
files <- group_1_file_names

move_files <- function(x){
  file.copy( from = file.path("Path_For_Origin_Folder", x) ,
               to = file.path("Path_For_New_folder", x) )}

lapply(files, move_files)
```

Any suggestions on how to make this work with the partial file names?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `Sys.glob(.)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this uses glob-style patterns:

```r
for (nm in group_1) {
  files <- Sys.glob(file.path("Path_For_Origin_Folder", paste0(nm, "*")))
  if (length(files)) file.copy(files, "Path_For_New_folder/")
}
```

Or you can do it in one-step with regex patterns:

```r
files <- list.files("Path_For_Origin_Folder",
  pattern = paste0("(", paste(group_1, collapse = "|"), ")"),
  full.names = TRUE)
if (length(files)) file.copy(files, "Path_For_New_folder/")
```

For this, if your "pattern" contains any regex symbols (obscurely `*`, `+`, `(`, `)`, `[`, `]`, or `|`, but notably and very easily `.`), then you will need to escape them, e.g., something like `gsub("[.]", "[.]", group_1)`.

Comment: I never think to use `Sys.glob()` but this looks nice. Do you know if this has performance advantages (or disadvantages) when compared with regex and `lapply()`?

Comment: I haven't benchmarked it if that's what you mean, but I'd think the most expensive part from R's perspective would be two calls to `Sys.glob` or one call to `list.files`, but if it's local then even that should be fine. `lapply`-vs-`for` is not an issue, effectively identical. `file.copy` has the potential of being the longest running portion here, and that'll be the case regardless of the method used to determine the files to move.

Comment: Thanks - not sure why I didn't think of using the `pattern` parameter of `list.files()` with the concatenated regex, seems the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could concatenate the file names and use that as a regular expression to subset the files:

```r
files_in_dir  <- dir(".")

files_to_copy  <- files[
    grepl(paste(group_1, collapse = "|"), files)
]

lapply(files, move_files)
```

Here's an example with your input vector:

```r
files_in_dir  <- c("ABC1211_987XYZ.txt", "ABC1212_986XYZ.txt", "ABC1213_985XYZ.txt")
files[grepl(paste(group_1, collapse = "|"), files)]
# [1] "ABC1211_987XYZ.txt" "ABC1213_985XYZ.txt"
```

Also `grep(paste(group_1, collapse = "|"), files, value = TRUE)` returns the same thing.